# Pass props to React container component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React. I'm displaying a list of songs and I want to allow the user to add songs to their favourites. I'm using Redux to store the favourited songs. My PlayList component looks like:

```
import AddSong from '../containers/AddSong'

class Playlist extends Component {

    render(){
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Playlists</h1>
            <ul className="container">
              {this.state.items.map(item =>
                <li key={item.track.id}>
                    {item.track.name} by {item.track.artists[0].name}
                    <img src={item.track.album.images[0].url} height="150" width="150" />

                    <AddSong title={item.track.name} />

                </li>
              )}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );

    }
    ...
}
```

So I passing the song name to AddSong with `<AddSong title={item.track.name} />`

And AddSong looks like:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addSong } from '../actions'

let AddSong = ({ dispatch }) => {
  let input

  console.log('this is ', this);

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault()
          // GET SONG FROM PROPS AND DISPATCH
          //dispatch(addSong(input.value))

        }}
      >
        <input
          ref={node => {
            input = node
          }}
        />
        <button type="submit">
          Add Song
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
AddSong = connect()(AddSong)

export default AddSong
```

However, `this` is an object with the property:

```
{
   a: Connect(props, context)
}
```

How do I get the song title in AddSong?

**EDIT**

So this is what I have now, Im passing the song title to AddSong here:

```
<AddSong song={item.track.name} title={item.track.name} />
```

I'm passing the song title in as song and title to show what happens.

In AddSong, I have:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

    const {song:song} = state; // or whatever the reducer called
    return {song};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({

    addSong: (value) => dispatch(addSong(value)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddSong);
```

And at the top of AddSong I'm doing:

```
let AddSong = ({ dispatch, ...props }) => {
  let input

  console.log('props is ', props);
```

The console outputs:

```
props is  Object {song: undefined, title: "Young Blood"}
```

I've changed the button to:

```
<button onClick={(value)=>props.addSong(value)}>
  Add Song
</button>
```

When I click, this gives the error:

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `songs[0].text` of type `object` supplied to `SongList`, expected `string
```

Comment: are you asking how to get the data from the store as props inside the connected component?

Comment: let AddSong = ({ dispatch, ...props }) => {}

Comment: @Sag1v Im trying to get the song title inside of AddSong...

Comment: @MadeInMoon how so I then get the song title?

Comment: @Mark pass from where you call `AddSong` (`<AddSong title={item.track.name} song={item} />`) or as suggested by the Israel Martins's answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function

```
const mapStateToProps = function(store) {
  return {
    data: store.data
  };
  }

AddSong = connect(mapStateToProps)(AddSong)
```

Comment: Thanks. When the user clicks the Add Song button in AddSong, how do I then get that song title?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the reducer and you want to access the state via props, if this the case you can mapStateToProps e.g.

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

    const {song:song} = state; // or whatever the reducer called
    return {song};

};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    addSong: (value) => dispatch(addSong(value)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddSong);
```

then you can just write `this.props.song`.

Comment: Thanks. When the user clicks the Add Song button in AddSong, how do I then get that song title?

Comment: you need to have an action, which is I guess in your case the addSong(value), by using mapDispatchToProps just onClick={(value)=>this.props.addSong(value).
i hope you understood.

Comment: Do you mean have an onClick() on the button?

Comment: Yes the onClick on button